# How to take picture and set it as background using phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap to build my app, In the app i am building i have a camera which turns on when i open the app and i see camera controls. once i capture the picture the captured picture should get set as my app background image. how can i do that?

here's what i have tried:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            showOverlay: false
     });

    function onSuccess(imageURI) {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            image.src = imageURI;
            alert(image.src);
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(image.src)";

    }

    function onFail(message) {
            /*alert("you are closing the camera")*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onSuccess` function should look like this

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
   var image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + image + ")";
}
```